# Java Processing - using text() but nothing showing on the window

Tags: java, processing

The program then uses the information contained within this array to display statistics on this data, and to notify when it comes across a new person (i.e. somebody with an age of 0).

I put the code into Processing, but nothing showed up in the window the program created and the window's color is grey instead of black. I use a MacBook. Could you tell me what's the problem?

```
size(500,500) ;
background(0);

int n = 4000;
int[] x = new int[n];
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

for(int i=0; i<4000; i=i+1){
  x[i] = int(random( 101 ));
}

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if(x[i] <= 20){ 
    a = a+1;
    if(x[i]==0){
       println("New Person!");
     } 
   }
   else if(x[i]<51 && x[i]>20){
     b++;
   }
   else{
     c = c+1;
   } 
}  

text("0-20: " + a, 20, 20);

text("21-50: " + b, 20, 40);

text("51-100: " + c, 20, 60);
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious issue in this code. The code works fine for me.

Comment: Your code also works fine for me. Are you sure this is exactly the code you're running?

Comment: I can also confirm this runs fine: after the 8000 loops run (~1.2s on my machine), the 3 texts appear white on black.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine. Are you using processing 3? Have you tried restarting processing and/or your computer?